# Problem of alignment of blocks in two columns?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, columns, block

Consider the following code of a beamer frame:

```
\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{block}{Single column}
\justifying
This is a block.
\end{block}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{exampleblock}{Left}
\justifying
This is the first column.
\end{exampleblock}
\end{column}
\begin{column}[right]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{exampleblock}{Right}
\justifying
This is the second column.
\end{exampleblock}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

It produces the following result:
[image: Illustration]

The problem is that the right block is not right aligned with the full text width.

How to align it correctly ?

EDIT:

I load the following packages:

```
\usepackage{marvosym} %
\usepackage{ragged2e} % define justifying
\usepackage{hyperref} %
\usepackage{transparent} %
```

Comment: Maybe `\hfill` between the columns? Or `.5\textwidth`?

Comment: "Left" has no descenders.  add `\strut` to match height of "Right".  (this in addition to `\hfill`.)

Comment: How is the macro `\justifying` defined? Do you load some package that defines this macro?

Comment: @Mico:  added the answer to you question
@Sigur: `\hfill` does not change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @barbarabeeton has observed in a comment, it turns out to be necessary to insert something like `\strut` -- `\mathstrut` will do too -- in the left-hand `exampleblock` environment, i.e., the one that contains the word `Left`, which doesn't contain letters with descenders -- whereas `Right` does.

In the LaTeX kernel, `\strut` is defined as zero-width and thus invisible vertical rule with height `0.7\baselineskip` and depth `0.3\baselineskip`; its total height is therefore equal to `\baselineskip`. In contrast, a `\mathstrut`'s total height is that of the `)` character. A `\strut` is thus slightly taller than a `\mathstrut`. Either way, both `\strut` and `\mathstrut` provide enough depth to the left-hand block.

In general, it may be necessary to provide struts in *both* the left-hand and right-hand exampleblock environments, especially if one block contains words with ascenders but no descenders (e.g., `left`, `black`) and the other contains words with descenders but no ascenders (e.g., `green`, `uvwxyz`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{marvosym} %
\usepackage{ragged2e} % define justifying
\usepackage{transparent} %
\usepackage{hyperref} %
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{block}{Single column}
\justifying
This is a block.
\end{block}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{exampleblock}{Left\strut}
\justifying
This is the first column.
\end{exampleblock}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{exampleblock}{Right}
\justifying
This is the second column.
\end{exampleblock}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have the same problem but strut doesn't seem to help in order to align blocks. Is there any other tool or command to do this?

Comment: @Charlie - Please consider posting your inquiry as a new question and providing information about the sizes of the blocks involved. Without this information it's going to be difficult to provide specific suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\newsavebox{\squaredblocktext}
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
    \par\vskip\medskipamount%
    \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-1.5ex\relax][l]{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title}
            \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle%
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \begin{lrbox}{\squaredblocktext}%
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
                \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{block end}{
            \end{minipage}%
        \end{lrbox}%
        {\parskip0pt\par}%
        \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title}{}
        {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
        \usebeamerfont{block body}%
        \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-1.5ex\relax][l]{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
            \usebox{\squaredblocktext}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }\vskip\smallskipamount%
}

\setbeamertemplate{block example begin}{
    \par\vskip\medskipamount%
    \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-1.5ex\relax][l]{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title example}
            \usebeamerfont*{block titleexample}\insertblocktitle%
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \begin{lrbox}{\squaredblocktext}%
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
                \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body example}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
            }

\setbeamertemplate{block example end}{
            \end{minipage}%
        \end{lrbox}%
        {\parskip0pt\par}%
        \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title example}{}
        {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body example}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
        \usebeamerfont{block body example}%
        \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-1.5ex\relax][l]{%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body example}%
                \usebox{\squaredblocktext}
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }\vskip\smallskipamount%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        \begin{block}{Single column}
            This is a block.
        \end{block}
        \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
            \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
                \begin{exampleblock}{Left}
                    This is the first column.
                \end{exampleblock}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
                \begin{exampleblock}{Right}
                    This is the second column.
                \end{exampleblock}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```